# Know username who is working on remote desktop

Tags: networking, windows, remote-desktop, desktop

We are a team of 20 people we have a machine that is used by everyone. We take remote desktop of that machine to work on. so if somebody is working and i want to take that i have to ask everyone  in the team who is using it so that i can take the remote desktop of it. Is there any way so that i can directly know who is using remote desktop of that machine so that i don't have to ask everybody in the team.

Comment: This is a Remote Desktop and Windows question, not an InfoSec question.

Comment: Do you log on to the same session each time with a communal username/password? Or do you each log on with your own credentials? If you each use your own credentials then you could UNC to the "Users" folder of the remote computer where you could see the user who's profile folder was last modified to find out who's on. Or you could open the computer's event viewer which would tell you who logged on.

Answer (score 2):

If you can logon to that PC via remote desktop, you can use Task Manager and Users tab to view all users (active/disconnected). 
If you cannot logon, then you can remotely issue the following command:
`query session /server:hostnamehere`
to get the same list of users.